# how to add inline style width:calc(100% / var) in reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs

```
 for (let i = 0; i < divCount.length; i++) {
        var radio = divCount[i].getElementsByClassName("radio_count");
        for (var index = 0; index < radio.length; index++) {
            var element: any = radio[index];
            console.log(element);
             var style ="width:calc(100% / " + element + ")";
            element.style = style;
        }

    }
```

1. i want add inline style
2. set dynamic value in 100% divided
   ex. width:clac(100% / var);
   how can i do this ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) should help.

```
<div style={{width: `calc(100% / ${yourVariable})`}}></div>
```

Example https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/81579/

Comment: but we can use $

Comment: It's not jQuery. See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 3):

What @Andrew wrote is correct, however here's a non ES2015/ES6 version (the question did not specify):

In the react component render, you can use the following JSX:

```
render: function() {
    var dynamicWidth = 'calc(100% / ' + value + ')';
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{width: dynamicWidth}}></div>
      </div>
    );
```

Basically how this works is on each render that string gets interpolated.
What @Andrew has shown you is just a better syntax available to do the same thing in ES6

`calc(100% / ${value})` is conceptually equivalent to `'calc(100% / ' + value + ')'`

Answer (score 0):

1.Inline styles can be added to a component in ReactJS as shown below:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
            Div to be styled
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or by passing a style object to the component:

```
render() {
    const divStyle = {
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    };

    return (
        <div style={divStyle}>
            Div to be styled
        </div>
    )
}
```

2. In order to set a dynamic width based on the number of child elements as you have described, I would recommend using CSS. Use `display: flex` on the wrapping element and `flex-grow: 1` on the inner element.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/edyjt34r/

Answer (score 0):

**Without using Calc function  you can  this desired result**

```
<div style = width: `${100 / ${yourVariable}}%`></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (let i = 0; i < divCount.length; i++) {
        var radio = divCount[i].getElementsByClassName("radio_count");
        for (var index = 0; index < radio.length; index++) {
            var element: any = radio[index];
            console.log(element);
            let width = 100 / radio.length;
            element.style.width=width + "%";
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the project is truly based on React.js, it'll be better if you use React's state and render features, instead of querying the DOM and _imperatively_ mutating it.

Comment: i am using reactjs with typescripts without jquery.